# location.reload with cache

Tags: javascript, caching, reload

*If you have a better title for this question feel free to edit.*

For the longest time, I always used `location.reload()` to reload the page - it's the most logical thing to do, right?

But I recently noticed that it is not the equivalent to F5, as I had initially thought, but more of Ctrl+F5. All images and other linked files were re-requested from the server, when all I wanted to do was reload the page.

I discovered that I could use `location.replace(location.href)` and this appears to achieve the effect I want: reload the page but retrieve linked files from cache.

Is this ideal? Is there a better way than this? Have I overlooked any pitfalls this method may have?

(note: I already have cache-busting management on linked files such as scripts, by appending the `filemtime` as a query string)

Comment: window.location.reload(false); will reload from the cache...

Comment: @TGxANAHEiiMx ["If it is false or not specified, the browser may reload the page from its cache."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) - Note the use of "may", and "the page" - it doesn't say anything about "will", or linked files.

Comment: Ah, point taken. Not the best since you are approaching it from a 'best practices' stand point and not just a 'functional' situation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In answer to my own question, there is a massive pitfall: When the location contains a hash, the browser will jump to that hash instead of reloading the page.

The solution I implemented is as follows:

```
reload = (function() {
    var m = location.search.match(/[?&]__hash=([^&]+)/);
    if( m) location.hash = unescape(m[1]);
    return function() {
            var h = location.hash;
            if( h == "") {
                    location.replace(location.href);
            }
            else {
                    var s = location.search;
                    s = s.replace(/[?&]__hash=[^&]+/,'');
                    s += (s == "" ? "?" : "&")+"__hash="+escape(h);
                    location.replace(location.pathname+s);
            }
    };
})();
```

Assuming nothing on the server side uses `$_GET['__hash']`, this can be used safely.